# Implementation of single mobile login of an account

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework

Iam working on Android mobile app development using Ionic with Angular framework. The backend used is Node js api.

I successfully created registration and user login to enter into the app.

Now my requirement is to implement single mobile login. i.e if logged in from one account of a mobile device, must logout from others devices if the same user is logged in.

Please help me how can i do this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well on a small scale you can do it in different ways

You can maintain a status of user isloggedin: boolean in yr database or backend and verify if the user tries to log in again. You will have to change the status every time user logs in and logs out. So is user is logged in status would be true and if user again tries to log in you will restrict or do anything as per your requirement.

You can also simply maintain a list of users currently logged in on your backend and verify it for repetitive log in.

these are of course not the only way, but sure are some of the simpliest way to achieve your goal. I suggest to use it only of your app has not huge user base as this solutions basically based on brute force. if user base is huge you may want to go to some advanced algorithms to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Milan Lakhani, thank you soo much for your response. if possible can you share some reference links as iam not technically good at backend part. I used broker api calls for retriving backend data. Thanks again